# Proving the Fourier Transform of $h(-t) = H(f)^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, random-variables, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I came across a textbook asking the following question:

If $h(t)$ is a real-valued function, show that the Fourier transform of $h(−t)$ is $H(f)^*$, where the asterisk ∗ denotes the complex conjugate.

Answer:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(-t)e^{-j2\pi ft}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\theta)e^{-j2\pi f(-\theta)}d{\theta} $$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\theta)e^{j2\pi f\theta}d{\theta}$$
$$=(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\theta)^*e^{j2\pi f\theta}d{\theta})^*$$
since $h(f)$ is real valued,
$$=(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\theta)e^{j2\pi f\theta}d{\theta})^* $$ 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(-t)e^{-j2\pi ft}dt = H(f)^* $$

**My question is:** 
In the first step, $-t$ is substituted with $\theta$. However, shouldn't there be a "-" sign? as $dt=-d\theta$ during the substitution such that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(-t)e^{-j2\pi ft}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-h(\theta)e^{-j2\pi f(-\theta)}d{\theta} $$

Comment: Yes, but it also switches the limits of integration, and switching them back adds another negative sign.

Comment: @copper.hat That's tricky but it does make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(-t)e^{-j2\pi ft}dt = \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} h(\theta) e^{-j2\pi f(-\theta)}(-d{\theta})\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(\theta) e^{-j2\pi f(-\theta)}d{\theta}\\
$$

The bounds flip and then the extra minus to flip them back.